# Jpa join with where clause in first an second tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with JPA and two tables
Entity Language

```
public class Language {

    @NotEmpty
    @Id
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean active;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "language", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<LanguageTranslation> languageTranslation;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder {
    // Lombok will add constructor, setters, build method
    }
  }
```

Entity LanguageTranslation

```
    public class LanguageTranslation {

      @EmbeddedId
      private LanguageTranslationId languageTranslationId;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @MapsId("languageCode")
      @JoinColumn(name = "language_code", nullable = false)
      @JsonIgnore
      private Language language;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @MapsId("languageLanguageCode")
      @JoinColumn(name = "language_language_code", nullable = false)
      @JsonIgnore
      private Language languageLanguage;

      @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
      @NotEmpty
      private String name;

      public LanguageTranslation(LanguageTranslationId languageTranslationId, @NotEmpty String name) 
    {
      super();
      this.languageTranslationId = languageTranslationId;
      this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder {
    // Lombok will add constructor, setters, build method
   }
}
```

ID

```
   @Embeddable
   public class LanguageTranslationId implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Column(name = "language_code")
     private String languageCode;

     @Column(name = "language_language_code")
     private String languageLanguageCode;

     @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
     public static class Builder {
       // Lombok will add constructor, setters, build method
     }
  }
```

Query

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT l FROM Language l " +
        "JOIN LanguageTranslation lt ON l.code = lt.languageTranslationId.languageCode " +
        "WHERE lt.languageTranslationId.languageLanguageCode = ?2 " +
        "AND l.code = ?1 AND l.active = true")
        Language findByCodeByTranslationAndActiveTrue(String id, String translation);
```

The problem is this WHERE lt.languageTranslationId.languageLanguageCode = ?2 it's useless. JPA doesn't execute this clause
Whith id = en_EN and translation = en_EN I have this

```
   {
    "code": "en_EN",
    "languageTranslation": [
    {
     "languageTranslationId": {
     "languageCode": "en_EN",
     "languageLanguageCode": "en_EN"
    },
    "name": "English"
  },
  {
    "languageTranslationId": {
    "languageCode": "en_EN",
    "languageLanguageCode": "es_ES"
  },
  "name": "Ingles"
  }
 ]
}
```

And normally I would have to have this

```
   {
    "code": "en_EN",
    "languageTranslation": [
   {
     "languageTranslationId": {
     "languageCode": "en_EN",
     "languageLanguageCode": "en_EN"
   },
   "name": "English"
  }
]
}
```

Comment: So you load a `Language` that has multiple translations via the `@OneToMany` and then expect these translations to be filtered somehow when you serialize that `Language` to Json. How will that work?

Comment: In native is simple the problem is JPA. in native after you serialize a json